# How to do this JSON request non-ajax?

Tags: json, http, post, request

How to do this request non-ajax but as a standard request from the browser where the user will see the answer of rest/something in his browser window?

```
var JSONObject= {"uname":uname, "password":password };
var jsonData = JSON.parse( JSONObject );    

    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "rest/something",
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: jsonData,
      dataType: "json"
    });
```

Edit: Why would you need this? Explanation: rest/something may return a content with content type application/pdf which should not be saved on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history API for mocking this behaviour.

See in: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will check this solution.